# mod_rewrite rewriterule?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

hello i have an anchor on my site. by calling my site the url will be:

```
http://site.com/page.php
```

by clicking a button the url will display an url that i would like to hide:

```
http://site.com/page.php#1
```

now i have found out that i can change this by using mod_rewrite tool. i tried this rule without success:

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.html$
RewriteRule ^.*\.html$ %1.php [L]
```

for calling the page as html or php and to hide the `#1` behind the .php

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./php#1=php$1
```

i really would appreciate if there is someone who could give me advise on how to solve this. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve this via mod_rewrite.

URL after `#` are not passed through server.

If you still want to achieve this, you may want to look into doing it via JavaScript:

```
<a href="#checkthisout" onclick="scrollHere">Check this out</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function scrollHere() {
    // Scroll to the anchor 
    //(you may need to look for some script to achieve this)

    return false; // to prevent URL overwriting
}
```

One such script is this [jQuery.scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.sg/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html).

Comment: okay, thanks so far. is there a way to realize that? and is it possible just to call a page without ending like http://site.com/page? thanks

Comment: Have a look at one of the JS-libraries (Jquery, or such). They usually provid some functions, that helps you handling the hashtags.

Comment: okay, i will look at it. one more question: how can i call that page without endings? all i could find was <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LWP::Simple
RewriteRule ^/.* http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/ [L,E=nolog:1]
</IfModule>  but that doesnt work.

Comment: You can't strip `#` from web server.

Answer (score 0):

The hashtag is never sent to the server, thus you simply cannot create a rule, that based on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to remove # tag.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Your text</a>.
```

So when you write "javascript:void(0);" in href attribute of a tag and thats it.

Comment: That's just voiding the linking ability of `<a>`. It really doesn't do anything (which I don't think is what you're look for).

Comment: You can call a Javascript function in place of 'javascript:void(0);' and there you can do something like this..  $.post(your_url,
                function(data) {
                 // alert(data);
                });

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<a href='page'>Home Page</a>

<a href='page/1'>Page 1</a>
<a href='page/2'>Page 2</a>
<a href='page/3'>Page 3</a>
```

Rewriting as

```
RewriteRule ^$ page.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?([0-9]*)/?$ page.php?index=$2 [L]
```

And check for index in php

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['index']))
{
      $pageNo =$_GET['index'];
}
//based on page NO display contents
```

?>